# Truecrypt with a short password and one keyfile

Tags: truecrypt

If I use short password like ' myvolume ' and use a key file with it says

> WARNING: Short passwords are easy to crack using brute force
>   techniques! We recommend choosing a password consisting of more than
>   20 characters. Are you sure you want to use a short password?

What I know is if I use keyfile truecrypt use full password length, so why does it warn me?

When I use a keyfile they take the first 1024 bytes and made a password from it. Is there any way that make me extract the password so I can write it down to use it if I dont hve the keyfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to compromise your keyfile stored on some harddrive or usb-stick than the password stored in your brain.

At least if you don't write the password down somewhere.

Comment: not true cuz if i use the keyfile only no WARRING.?

Comment: because the warning is generated by the lenght checker which seemingly just doesn't take into account if you use a keyfile or not.